# Get code of methods while iterating over object

Tags: javascript

I know in javascript I can iterate over an object to get all of it's properties.  If one or more of the properties is a method, is it possible to see what code is in the method instead of just the method name? E.g.

```
var a = someobject;

for (property in a) {
  console.log(property);
}
```

Is it possible to get method code in a way similar to this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It actually works. Try:

```
var a = {};
a.id = 'aaa';
a.fun = function(){alert('aaa');}
for (x in a) {
    var current = a[x].toString();
    if(current.indexOf('function') == 0){
        current = current.substring(current.indexOf('{')+ 1, current.lastIndexOf('}'));
    }
console.log(current);
}
```

But it will not work for browser native code.

Comment: To add to Akhil's answer, you can also filter the list of properties using `typeof(property) === 'function'` to display only the properties that are functions.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to run, but I am expecting that when it encounters the a.fun method it would just return "function" instead of the code within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `toString`, per the [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). i.e:

```
//EX:
var a = {method:function(x) { return x; }};

//gets the properties
for (x in a) {
  console.log(a[x].toString());
}
```

You can also use [`toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) but it is **NOT** part of the standard.

PS: attempting to reliably iterate through an object with a `for : loop` is nontrivial and dangerous (`for..in` only iterates over `[[Enumerable]]` properties, for one), try to avoid such constructs. I would ask why, exactly, are you doing this?

Comment: I didn't know it was dangerous.  In what way?

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/ outlines some reasons why `for...in` can be evil.

Comment: I work on a SaaS platform and want to see the code behind the various objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toString` method on the function

i.e.

```
function hello() {
    var hi = "hello world";
    alert(hi);
}  

alert(hello.toString());​
```

Update: The reason it wasn't working in JSFiddle was because I forgot to add the output inside of either `console.log` or `alert` - http://jsfiddle.net/pbojinov/mYqrY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zeCcH/   Expected output is: "var hi = "hello world"; alert(hi);"  correct?

Comment: sorry I forgot to put `hello.toString();` inside of a `console.log` or `alert`. `console.log` will not work in JSFiddle but will work inside Chrome Developer Tools Console. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `a` is an object, you should be able to use the square bracket notation and query a value from by argument with the same name as the objects property. For example:

```
a[ property ];
```

If you log `typeof( property )`, it will return `"string"` which is what we want.